# LOOP IN PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a record of dates and logid. 
I wonder if I could display the dates depending on the logid like 2017-09-01 to 2017-09-05 for logid = **015511439** then 2017-09-01 to 2017-09-05 for **9272276416**.

I just made loop PHP something like this

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 1; $x++)
```

then at mysql it is just a plain

```
select date, logid from myTable
```

.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you need the loop for though?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I just need to re-arrange or sort the records.

Comment: `select date, logid at myTable`??? Is this query???!!!

Comment: Srsly @B.Desai?

Comment: You just have edited your question. Your query was wrong that why I asked you

Comment: Yeah thanks. I did not checked my query before posting

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
    $results=mysql_query($query);
    $row_count=mysql_num_rows($results);

    while ($row_users = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        //output a row here
if($row_users['logid']=="015511439"){
        echo ($row_users['date']);
        echo ($row_users['logid']);
        }
    }
```

or without if condition you can simply do this using a where clause.... Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: I already did this. Did not get the display Im trying to achieve